# How to put title in navbar in mobile mode with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you look at [this site](http://buffalosw.com) and resize to the size of a tablet or mobile phone, it collapses the navbar down and keeps the current title as the selected item in a pull down.  If you look at the navbar [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and collapse it down to table or mobile phone, you can see how the title is missing.

I would LOVE

1. to put a title in the navbar for mobile phones
2. replace the icon with a pulldown icon so it is more obvious to users on phones it is a pulldown and it is clickable with their finger(not so obvious with their current design).

Is there anyway to do this?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: So you'd like it to look like the Bootstrap site, except display Home/Brand link in center, and dropdown icon on right (instead of icon with 3 bars)?

Comment: display the tab I am on in the center.  For buffalosw.com, this would be either Home, Products, Clients, About US or Contact depending on which page I am on.  Of course, I can use a variable of ${tab_title} easily enough, but basically what you said is right as I can replace with variable.

Comment: and yes, drop down icon on right instead of icon with 3 bars which is very unknown to users as a clickable html element(not sure why they would use that).

Comment: faking it out somehow making it look like a select box even though it is not would be the ultimate usability change as well though not sure that is possible or not(and something good enough is fine)